# How to convert Docx to Html using C# console application without using any third party dll

Tags: c#

is there anyone suggest me the solution to convert .Docx(word file) file to Html using C# without using third party dll?

i directly save the file into html using C# , that's generating extra xml and style sheet.. Please suggest me without these many extra files..

Comment: You can read this guid https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266097/convert-from-word-document-to-html

Comment: How do you generate the html right now? I understand, when you say "i directly save", it's not you who is saving. Are you using word interop? What are you using?

Comment: yes I am using using word interop, but i don't want to use any third party dll here