# Word viewer in asp web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, com, activex

I've to create one asp web application page for show .docx file( with exact alignment text,images, table etc) and also table of content(like tree view of that document). I would like to ask, Is there any open source ActiveX control or plugin or something else to achieve the specific task .  I already done it in windows form application but now want to do it asp web form . i used **dsoframer** control in windows application . please make me to achieve that.

Comment: It's already answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291305/ms-word-viewer-c-sharp-net-automation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look into following article,

[Link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/scottlysle/wordinweb01202007101216am/wordinweb.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is support to render a .docx file as HTML - I can't speak to how accurately it renders in the webpage verse desktop version of Word.  Still, there is a tutorial here:
http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2008/01/11/Preview-Word-files-%28docx%29-in-HTML-using-ASPNET-OpenXML-and-LINQ-to-XML.aspx